# How can I not display blank rows in an excel diagram?

Tags: excel, diagram, pivot-table

I am getting data from PowerPivot to an Excel table. It has variable length. I also have some calculated columns next to it. I would like to make a diagram out of it.

The problem is, as I specify the data ranges and such, I have to oversize, in case the data returned provides more rows. (Ex. in this case i have data till a20, but in an other case I could have data till a30 or more. So I select the range to a40 to be safe.) I have to specify this manually (not select from the pivot table) because of the calculated columns and other labels and exceptions.

In the diagram, it shows these blank rows. This is unnecesary. 
[image]

How can I instruct excel, not to display those rows, that are blank? (Even if I delete all formulas, and the rows are completely blank, it still displays it.)

Thanks for the help. Sziro.

Answer (score 1):

When I have been facing a similar problem, I have created named dynamic ranges, and made the diagram refer to these ranges.

Here is how I create a dynamic range for a data series stored from range A2 to A40 in Sheet1.

1. Define a name for you dynamic range using a formula like this in the "Refers to" input box:

   =OFFSET('Sheet1'!$A$2,0,0,COUNTA('Sheet1'!$A$2:$A$40),1)
2. Now make your series value refer to the name you have given the dynamic range. If you have named the range "Sales" you should make the diagram series values refer to: "='Sheet1'!Sales". It is important that you also refer to the name of the sheet, otherwise it won't work.

Comment: Thanks, will look along these lines.

Comment: I have seen this approach. The dynamic range does calculate cells correctly, however I need this to be automatic. So it only writes the correct cells only once to the diagram, than the diagram contains only static length cells. This does not update with the update of the dynamic range. Am I missing something?